# How to Keep Toggle Button state in Windows phone 8 application?

Tags: windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit, togglebutton

I create a toggle button and its working fine . But problem is that how can i Keep previous toggle activity, I mean when application is exit and reopen, it should display the previous toggle state . Here is my code

XAML:

`<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggle" Content="ToggleSwitch is on"  Header="ToggleSwitch"/>`

CS :

```
public partial class EnglishSub : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public BanglaSub()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.toggle.Checked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Checked);
        this.toggle.Unchecked += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(toggle_Unchecked);
        this.toggle.Content = "ToggleSwitch is off";
    }

    void toggle_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.toggle.Content = "ToggleSwitch is off";
        this.toggle.SwitchForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        MessageBox.Show("Disable");
    }

    void toggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.toggle.Content = "ToggleSwitch is on";
        this.toggle.SwitchForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        MessageBox.Show("Enable");
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated your code to fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use IsolatedStorageSetings to store application data. and read it when your app page is loaded again. here is how

```
public bool GetToggleValue()
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("toggleValue"))
        {
           return  bool.Parse(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["toggleValue"].ToString());


        }
        else return false;
    }
```

call above method in your page load to set the toggle value

and set checked unchecked value in the settings in your checked unchecked event handlers here is how

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("toggleValue", true);
IsolatedStorageSettings.Save();
```

Comment: Don't forget to `IsolatedStorageSettings.Save()` after you modify settings, otherwise the value won't be stored when you exit the app.